# Convert this Query to Entity Framework LINQ

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

Can someone help me convert this SQL Query to EntityFramework LINQ. I don't know how to do Inner Join in EF.

```
select * from UserActivities INNER JOIN LoginHistories
    ON UserActivities.iLoginHistoryId = LoginHistories.iLoginHistoryId
    AND iUserId = 15
```

Comment: Please post your LINQ code and the errors you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a rough estimate (not enough context):

```
var db = GetDbContextSomehow();
var query = from ua in db.UserActivities
            join lh in db.LoginHistories on ua.iLoginHistoryId equals lh.iLoginHistoryId
            where ua.iUserId == 15
            select ua;
```

Comment: Will this return a list of values in query? I have delete these selected items from DB. so shall I use foreach loop to delete items to delete from DB? like foreach(var q in query){db.UserActivities.DeleteObject(q);}

Comment: @DawoodAwan - that would (after SaveChanges()) delete all UserActivities returned by this query.

Comment: you mean after foreach loop db.SaveChanges()?